# How to design output in command line in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the out put I get. I tried to change the set page but still this is in two line:

```
REG#       FNAME
---------- --------------------------------------------------
LNAME
--------------------------------------------------
SST005     John
Lucas

PKR008     John
Lucas

PKR768     John
Lucas


    REG#       FNAME
    ---------- --------------------------------------------------
    LNAME
    --------------------------------------------------
    QRT834     John
    Lucas

    PKR008     John
    Lucas

    LUCY02
```

how can I print each row only in one row. here is my script:

```
SELECT TRUCK.REG# , EMPLOYEE.FNAME, EMPLOYEE.LNAME
FROM TRUCK
LEFT OUTER JOIN TRIP
ON TRUCK.REG# = TRIP.REG# 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DRIVER
ON DRIVER.L# = TRIP.L#
LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE
ON EMPLOYEE.E# = DRIVER.E#
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL*Plus commands in your script:

```
set pagesize 0 -- SET PAGESIZE number_of_lines
set heading off -- No headers
set linesize 200 -- Line size 
etc.
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch7.htm